# How to read and parse .json file in gradle.kts?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

my json is

```
{"enable": true}
```

place under asset folder in android studio

so I need to get that value and use it inside build.gradle.kts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
gradle.buildFinished {
try {
    val file = File("app/src/main/assets/soundEnable.json")
    val json = groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(file.readText()) as Map<String, String>
    if (json["enable"] as Boolean) {
        //do something
    }
} catch (ignore: Throwable) {
    println("=======")
    println(ignore.localizedMessage)
    println(ignore.cause)
    println(ignore.stackTrace)
    println("=======")
}
```

}

Comment: It is works for sure I already tried

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `gradle.buildFinished` has now been deprecated.